# How to include a template.txt as a here-doc of a script

Tags: bash

I have a template file(`template.txt`):

```
Hello, $x
Hello, $y
```

I have a script file(`script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
$x=linux
$y=unix
# I want to include template.txt as a here-doc
```

How to include `template.txt` as a `here-doc` of `script.sh`.
So that, when I run `script.sh`, the output should be:

```
Hello, linux
Hello, unix
```

---

**Edit:**

I think `replace` is a good command for my job：

```
$ cat template.txt | replace '$x' linux '$y' unix
```

A more sophisticated tool:

```
$ cheetah compile template.tmpl
$ x=linux y=unix python template.py --env
```

Comment: Does it have to automatically detect and insert the available variables? What's wrong with using `sed` to simply replace occurrences of `$x` and `$y`?

Comment: That approach becomes harder to manage as the number of variables grows.  It can also be difficult to keep all your quoting correct.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using an actual here document in the template?

Comment: @larsks: The variable names can be stored in a list, so it would (a) be more secure than just using any variable name and (b) rather flexible

Comment: @NiklasB. Maybe you could post an example?

Comment: @larsks: I don't know bash too well, unfortunately. That's why I first wanted a statement by OP before putting any effort in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this function in one of my projects.  It builds an actual here document from the template and then executes it in the current shell using `.`:

```
# usage: apply_template /path/to/template.txt
apply_template () {
        (
        trap 'rm -f $tempfile' EXIT
        tempfile=$(mktemp $(pwd)/templateXXXXXX)

        echo 'cat <<END_TEMPLATE' > $tempfile
        cat $1 >> $tempfile
        echo END_TEMPLATE >> $tempfile

        . $tempfile
        )
}
```

Comment: "Duh."  And that would be all absent SO comment length requirements.

Comment: Just wanted to note, some people actually let other people write their templates ;)

Answer (score 7):

The following bash function evaluates arbitrary files as here documents, allowing bash to be used as a mini-template language. It does not require any temporary files.

```
#!/bin/bash

template() {
  file=$1
  shift
  eval "`printf 'local %s\n' $@`
cat <<EOF
`cat $file`
EOF"
}
```

Variables will be expanded from the environment or can be passed directly, e.g. for the template file

```
Hello $x, $y, $z
```

and snippet

```
y=42
for i in 1 2; do
  template template.txt x=$i z=end
done
```

the output will be

```
Hello 1, 42, end
Hello 2, 42, end
```

Note that arbitrary code in the template file will be executed as well, so make sure you trust whoever wrote it.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

x=linux
y=unix

cat << EOF
Hello, $x
Hello, $y
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat <<\! >template.txt
Hello, $x
Hello, $y
!
cat <<\! >replace
export "$@"
sed -e '1i\cat <<EOT' -e '$a\EOT' | sed ':a;$!{N;ba};e'
!
cat template.txt | replace x='Fred Flintstone' y='Barney Rubble'
Hello, Fred Flintstone
Hello, Barney Rubble
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my proposed solution:

```
eval $'cat <<\002\n'"$(<ifile)"$'\n\002' > ofile
```

`\002` can be replaced with any character or string that doesn't occur in the ifile. To delete any occurrences of the delimiting character in the input file:

```
eval $'cat <<\002\n'"$(tr -d '\002' < ifile)"$'\n\002' > ofile
```

This solution seems to resolve most issues but is notably vulnerable to command injection in the template file through `$(command)` directives.